# Microsoft Graph API - Share Sharepoint site only

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-sites

You can share a Sharepoint site without adding them to the member groups via the front-end (screenshot included). However I was wondering if there was a way to do this via the Microsoft Graph API?

I have scoured the docs, both v1 and beta and haven't found anything - so any help would be greatly welcomed.

[Graph API Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)
[image: Screenshot of front-end permission sharing]

Answer (score 0):

According to the Microsoft Graph user voice, this feature is currently unavailable in the Graph API and is currently a suggested feature - will update this answer if/when it is implemented

[Uservoice Sharepoint permission suggestion](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/39962137-add-to-ms-graph-api-work-with-sharepoint-permissio)